# How to append character values from a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, append, c++17

I am trying to create a function which takes a line of input, and creates a string for each number in the input. Then it needs to find the largest number out of the strings created.

For instance, if the line was "12.50 13 14.50 14", I would need the function to create strings with the values of "12.50", "13", "14.50", and "14", and then return "14.50" but as a string.  As the code runs currently, it will iterate through each character in the sentence, and correctly set the value of "ch" to the character of the input line in question. I cannot get the code to properly append the ch values to the new number.  Number begins as an empty string and the line
`number.append(1,ch)` appends nothing for each iteration of the code.

```
int cnt_space(int i, int count, char ch,string sentence1)
{
 
    // input sentence
    
    ch = sentence1[0];
 
    // counting spaces
    int greatest = 0;
    while (ch != '\0') {
        ch = sentence1[i];
        string number;
        
        if (isspace(ch))
            count++;
            cout << "number: " << number << endl;
        cout << "ch: " << ch << endl;
        number.append(1,ch);
        
       // if (number >= greatest)
       //     greatest = number;
 
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create strings for *each* value, if you only return one of them?

Comment: return count is a statement from earlier that only returns the number of spaces within the line. It was to help me debug and find for sure when I have hit a space

Comment: @Ryan Sanchez Why is the return type of the function int? And it is unclear what is the purpose of the function?

Comment: *I would need the function to create strings* -- Why?  Your task can be completed without doing this by using `std::istringstream` in a loop.  If you did that, there would be no need to check for spaces.  In other words, you've overcomplicated the task given to you.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is <string tokenization>. Given a string and a set of delimiting characters, a tokenizer function will split the string into a set of substrings (or tokens). You can then do further processing on each substring in turn.

There are many solutions for tokenizing in C++ depending on your specific use case.

Comment: If you really need to read one character at a time and build the number, I suggest you search the internet for "backus Naur floating point C++".

Comment: @RyanSanchez -- The answer by #ThomasMatthews illustrates my point.  When given a line of input as a string delimited by spaces, there is no need to write any code attempting to check for spaces.  The `istringstream` class acts just like if you entered that line from the keyboard, except that instead of using the `std::cin` stream, you use the `std::istringstream` stream.  Note that you don't write code to check `std::cin` for spaces, you just say `cin >> mydata;` and it just magically works -- the same with `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution based on my understanding of your requirements:

```
std::string Max_Number_As_String(const std::string& text)
{
    std::istringstream  text_stream(text);
    double max_value = 0.0;
    double value;
    while (text_stream >> value)
    {
        if (value > max_value) max_value = value;
    }
    std::string value_as_string = std::to_string(max_value);
    return value_as_string;
}
```

The above code converts the input string to a stream, then uses `operator>>` to read the numbers for the string.  A running maxima is maintained.  After all the numbers are read, the maxima is converted to a string and returned.

Comment: I would start `max_value` at `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`, in case the input contains negative numbers.